# BeautifulSoup find_all div by class returns empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a div tag by class to find all the available listings on the website. Currently there are 37 listings, but my code is returning an empty list. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.premiervolvocarsoverlandpark.com/used-volvo/overland-park-ks.htm'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

requests = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'vehicle-card-details-container'})
requests
```

Comment: You're able to verify that the 'response' is non-empty? And if it's non-empty, that it has divs of the form you need?

Comment: I printed out the 'soup' and while the class name 'vehicle-card-details-container' is in the webpage when I inspect the HTML, it is not in the soup. It may be dynamically loaded.

Comment: Change your request to: 'requests = soup.find_all('h1', {'class': 'ddc-page-title'})' and it will return the element. Your code is correct, but as @pbuck said below, the content hasn't been loaded into the DOM yet.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman- tried changing it ddc-page-title. List is still blank.

Answer (score 1):

The data you see is loaded via Javascript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can simulate this request with `requests` module. For example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.premiervolvocarsoverlandpark.com/apis/widget/SITEBUILDER_OVERLAND_PARK_KS_1:inventory-data-bus1/getInventory?start={}"

for page in range(0, 4):
    u = url.format(10 * page)
    data = requests.get(u).json()

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for i in data["inventory"]:
        print("".join(i["title"]), i["pricing"]["retailPrice"])
```

Prints:

```
2019 Volvo  S60 T5 Momentum Sedan $32,000
2019 Volvo  S60 T5 Momentum Sedan $37,000
2019 Volvo  S60 T6 Inscription Sedan $42,490
2020 Volvo  S60 T6 Momentum Sedan $39,000
2019 Volvo  S60 T6 Momentum Sedan $37,000
2018 Volvo  S90 T5 Momentum Sedan $36,623
2022 Volvo  V90 Cross Country B6 Wagon $62,205
2022 Volvo  V90 Cross Country B6 Wagon $58,155
2021 Volvo  XC40 R-Design SUV $45,000
2019 Volvo  XC40 R-Design SUV $40,000
2017 Volvo  XC60 T5 Dynamic SUV $26,500
2020 Volvo  XC60 T5 Inscription SUV $47,000
2019 Volvo  XC60 T5 Inscription SUV $45,500
2021 Volvo  XC60 T5 Momentum SUV $45,000
2019 Volvo  XC60 T5 Momentum SUV $43,591
2019 Volvo  XC60 T5 Momentum SUV $43,500
2015 Volvo  XC60 T6 SUV $0
2021 Volvo  XC60 T6 Inscription SUV $56,200
2019 Volvo  XC60 T6 Inscription SUV $46,500
2021 Volvo  XC60 T6 Momentum SUV $45,000
2021 Volvo  XC60 T6 Momentum SUV $48,000
2021 Volvo  XC60 T6 Momentum SUV $47,688
2019 Volvo  XC60 T6 R-Design SUV $52,000
2021 Volvo  XC90 T5 Momentum SUV $59,275
2019 Volvo  XC90 T5 R-Design SUV $55,482
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 Inscription SUV $58,688
2021 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $63,295
2021 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $56,000
2021 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $57,000
2020 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $58,000
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $53,104
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $51,359
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $52,000
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 Momentum SUV $55,000
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 R-Design SUV $60,862
2019 Volvo  XC90 T6 R-Design SUV $54,000
2019 Volvo  XC90 Hybrid T8 Inscription SUV $66,300
```

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental mis-understanding of web scraping.

The *page* `../overland-park-ks.htm` does not contain any dom elements with `class="vehicle-card-details-container"`. Instead, the *page* loads javascript which eventually loads a JSON file called `getInventory`, which contains the data you're probably interested in.

To properly web scrape, you have to understand how the browser loads multiple pages to construct what you see. Or use something like Selenium which does that work first.

Comment: I’m new to this. So how do I use selenium to get the list of elements with the class I’m looking for?

Comment: Read the docs for Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io It is a completely different library: elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('foo').